# How to write php code inside a new php file

Tags: php

```
$np = $_POST["np"]; // `sky` for example
$a = "inc/" . $np . ".php";
$new = fopen($a, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$str="$np='" . $np . "';";
fwrite($new, $str);
fclose($new);
```

I need to create a new `inc/.sky.php` file and write the following inside it:

```
$np = 'sky';
```

But what I get is:

```
sky='sky';
```

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe because you don't write spaces in your string? So you won't get any?! `$str="$np = '" . $np . "';";` <- here you go ?!

Comment: I hope you see the security hole you have here and this is not real production code (hint: what happens if I pass `../index.php` as `np` via post?)

Comment: Read up on the difference between single- and double-quoted strings on [this manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaim: It can even be worse in case php file handling is vulnerable to null-byte injection: `../.htaccess\0` or even `../../../../etc/apache2/httpd.conf\0` (not sure if it really is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$np = $_POST["np"]; // `sky` for example
$a = "inc/" . $np . ".php";
$new = fopen($a, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$str='$np = \'' . $np . "';";
fwrite($new, $str);
fclose($new);
```

The problem was that you are using `"` to define the string `$str`. Therefore, the **content** of `$np` was printed instead of the string `'$np'`.

Comment: You should really fix the security problem in your code. Using `$np=str_replace("/","",$_POST["np"]);` as the first line will make it a lot safer.

Answer (score 0):

Use single comma's
This will insert the $np variable into your sting

```
$str="$np='" . $np . "';";
```

This will insert np as text

```
$str='$np=\'' . $np . '\';';
```